# cannot access jar library

Tags: java, netbeans, ocr

I am working on a program that uses OCR to read an invoice and sort it accordingly. The program works fine in NetBeans, it works fine when i run from command prompt. However if i just right-click and run the jar application, the GUI will open, but when I click the button that would activate the OCR program (using ASPRISE for anyone who is familiar) it will not "scan" the invoice. I'm using a trial right now so i can pitch it to my company, don't have the 1500 lying around to purchase the license. When the jar library is accessed it pops up with a dialog box asking if you want to purchase the license. It does not do this unless you run the program in NetBeans or from the command prompt. It does not throw any exceptions with command prompt open...so the program is not accessing the jar file outside of a command prompt/IDE. If an ideal fix is unavailable, i would even settle for a solution to adding a command prompt window to open with the program if possible.

Comment: When you say "run the jar application", where is the jar sitting? Just inside your netbeans project's dist directory, or did you move it somewhere?

Comment: It is in the dist directory, when I "run the jar" I either run in netbeans or open up cmd and run java -jar filename.jar, either of those work. If I right click on the file and run with java se binary is when it does not work properly.

Comment: Sorry, wasnt logged in and wouldn't let me post comments. Fixed, but now cant delete answer.

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. They're the same command. Well. Almost. Running with Java(TM) SE binary from the GUI actually executes "javaw.exe" -jar %1 %* (assuming you're in windows), but if java -jar works, javaw -jar should too... is there a "lib" directory sitting there too?

Comment: Yes, the lib file is there. I left the file structure exactly as netbeans created it just to make sure I didnt mess up any file paths in the process but that is not it. My sqlite.jar file still works and it is contained in the lib folder as well...

Comment: What's your OS? I can't fathom that java -jar works correctly but javaw -jar does not. You're certain that the "java -jar your.jar" functions completely as expected and identically to running it within NetBeans?

Comment: Maybe it notices that there's no console (as is the case with javaw) and triggers the licence question (no idea how you'd manage that, but there are bettern minds than mine out there). You could always just put the "java -jar your.jar" command in a batch file in the directory with it. See if that works.

Comment: Will do thanks, ill let you know how it works out. I knew that there should be no normal reason why it wouldn't work, especially with my other jar libs working...was hopping there was some abstract solution.

Comment: Read their developer's guide. It says about software packaging and distributing. You might need a licence. Plus you need to 'Insert the directory path containing the n
ative library to the system path (for
Windows) or to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable (for other OS)' 
or 'Copy the native library to jre/bin directory – 'install' the library to the JVM'.

http://asprise.com/product/ocr/doc/DevelopersGuide-Java.pdf